# RewriteEngine: Ignore all query strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to ignore all query-strings in my redirect. How would I achieve this?

Basically, `/project/(.*)` should always redirect to `/?tag=project&id=$1`

```
/project/100?shareid=fromsomeemailprovider
```

should end et the ? and only redirect to Id 100.

Thank You!

I tried the following:

```
^/project/([^/]*)[/]?(.*)$
/?tag=project&id=$1&$2
```

to put the query-string behind another &, but this only works if the first URL hast a `/` at the end of it, which it often hasn't and the RewriteRule can't detect the `?` sadly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question as your effort, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts. So this query string should be served by which file in backend? index.php OR some other .php file?

Comment: I'm working with Wordpress. So the Argument2 gets picked up by a plugin from index.php, i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(project)/(.*)/?$ index.php?tag=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

***Please make sure:***

- You clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.
- You make sure to keep your `index.php` file along with your htaccess rules file. Also add `/` in case both of these files are in root location in your system.